# Discord.js V14 how to edit an embed already sent?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im doing a fake giveaway system and i need to edit the "giveaway started" embed message with "giveaway ended" embed message [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08le9.png)

I couldn t find a solution for it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your message in a variable and then edit it when you need it.

```
const MSG = await message.channel.send({embeds: [yourEmbed]});

// Create a new Embed with which you're going to edit the message

const basicEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setDescription("Example")

// Then edit your original message

MSG.edit({embeds: [basicEmbed}});
```